# Creating dummy variables in R based on multiple chr values within each cell

Tags: r, string, character, dplyr, dummy-variable

I'm trying to create multiple dummy variables, based on one column called 'Tags' within my df (14 rows, 2 columns, Score and Tags. My problem is that in each cell there can be any number of chr values (up to about 30 values).

When I ask for:

```
 str(df$Tags)
```

R returns:

```
chr [1:14] "\"biologische gerechten\", \"certificaat van uitmuntendheid tripadvisor 2016\", \"gebruik streekproducten\", \"lactose intolera"| __truncated__ ...
```

And when I ask for:

```
df$Tags[1]
```

R returns:

```
[1] "\"biologische gerechten\", \"certificaat van uitmuntendheid tripadvisor 2016\", \"gebruik streekproducten\", \"lactose intolerantie\", \"met familie\", \"met vrienden\", \"noten allergie\", \"pinda allergie\", \"vegetarische gerechten\", chinees, gastronomisch, glutenvrij, kindvriendelijk, romantisch, traditioneel, trendy, verjaardag, zakelijk"
```

It seems that  the values within the first cell are not formatted the same (the values between comma's)

So what I wish for, is to create a dummy variable for each possible value that occurs within each cells. So the first new dummy should be called "biologische gerechten" (or any alike) and should show for each case whether the corresponding value is present (1) in the column 'Tags' or not (0).

i tried several things with 'dplyr' like:

```
df = mutate(df, biologisch = ifelse(Tags == "biologische gerechten", 1, 0))
```

R does create a new column 'biologisch', but it only contains zero's. Is there another way to separate all values and then create dummy variables for all possible values? Hope someone can help me, thank you!

Comment: How did you import the data? Please post `dput(df)` if it is not too large.

Comment: If I'm correctly understanding your problem, you could use `strsplit` to split apart the values within each cell of `Tags`, then use `sapply` and `grepl` to iterate checks for each tag option over all of the lists `strsplit` creates.

Comment: `df = mutate(df, biologisch = ifelse(grepl("biologische gerechten", Tags), 1, 0))`

Comment: Something like this will work, though the result will be quite wide: `myTags <- unique(unlist(strsplit(df$Tags, split=","))); dfNew <- cbind(df, lapply(myTags, function(i) grepl(i, df$Tags)))`

Comment: Your first line really works! So definitely I can do it manually like this! I'll just go through the most important values i need dummy variables for. The second line gives an error:

Comment: which is `Error in strsplit(df$Tags, split = ",") : non-character argument`

Comment: But the first part starts like: `structure(list(Tags = structure(c(27L, 16L, 4L), .Label = c("\"aan het water\", \"biologische gerechten\", \"certificaat van uitmuntendheid tripadvisor 2016\", \"er even tussenuit\", \"gebruik streekproducten\", \"iens topper 2016\", \"lactose intolerantie\", \"noten allergie\", \"pinda allergie\", \"vegetarische gerechten\", frans, glutenvrij, romantisch, wijnbar, zakelijk",`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one solution:

```
# make some toy data to test
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(Score = rnorm(10),
                 Tags = replicate(10, paste(sample(LETTERS, 5), collapse = ", ")),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# load stringr, which we'll use to trim whitespace from the split-up tags
library(stringr)

# use strsplit to break your jumbles of tags into separate elements, with a 
# list for each position in the original vector. i've split on commas here,
# but you'll probably want to split on slashes or slashes and quotation marks.
t <- strsplit(df$Tags, split = ",")

# get a vector of the unique elements of those lists. you may need to use str_trim
# or something like it to cut leading and trailing whitespace. you might also
# need to use stringr's `str_subset` and a regular expression to cut the result
# down to, say, only alphanumeric strings. without a reproducible example, though,
# i can't do that for your specific case here.
tags <- unique(str_trim(unlist(t)))

# now, use `sapply` and `grepl` to look for each element of `tags` in each list;
# use `any` to summarize the results; 
# use `+` to convert those summaries to binary;
# use `lapply` to iterate that process over all elements of `tags`;
# use `Reduce(cbind, ...)` to collapse the results into a table; and
# use `as.data.frame` to turn that table into a df.
df2 <- as.data.frame(Reduce(cbind, lapply(tags, function(i) sapply(t, function(j) +(any(grepl(i, j), na.rm = TRUE))))))

# assign the tags as column names
names(df2) <- tags
```

Voila:

```
> df2
   Y F P C Z K A J U H M O L E S R T Q V B I X G
1  1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
2  0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
3  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
4  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
5  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
6  0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
7  0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
8  0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
9  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1
```

Comment: hi, i understand your reasoning, but i'm not sure how to deal with the slashes, since it looks more like a mess when i look at the `dput(df)`

Comment: It's really hard to help you with that sub-problem when you don't post a reproducible example that includes it. Your original question seemed to focus on the problem I tried to address, i.e., how to split up the strings and get dummy variables for its components. If you can't solve this sub-problem on your own, it might be a good idea to start a new question focused on it.