# R function that creates indicator variable values unique between several columns

Tags: r, function, survey

I'm using the Drug Abuse Warning Network data to analyze common drug combinations in ER visits. Each additional drug is coded by a number in variables DRUGID_1....16. So Pt1 might have DRUGID_1 = 44 (cocaine) and DRUGID_3 = 20 (heroin), while Pt2 might have DRUGID_1=20 (heroin), DRUGID_3=44 (cocaine).

I want my function to loop through DRUGID_1...16 and for each of the 2 million patients create a new binary variable column for each unique drug mention, and set the value to 1 for that pt. So  a value of 1 for binary variable Heroin indicates that somewhere in the pts DRUGID_1....16 heroin is mentioned.

```
respDRUGID <- character(0) 
DRUGID.df <- data.frame(allDAWN$DRUGID_1, allDAWN$DRUGID_2, allDAWN$DRUGID_3)

Count <- 0
DrugPicker <- function(DRUGID.df){
  for(i in seq_along(DRUGID.df$allDAWN.DRUGID_1)){
    if (!'NA' %in% DRUGID.df[,allDAWN.DRUGID_1]){
      if (!is.element(DRUGID.df$allDAWN.DRUGID_1,respDRUGID)){
        Count <- Count + 1
        respDRUGID[Count] <- as.character(DRUGID.df$allDAWN.DRUGID_1[Count])
        assign(paste('r', as.character(respDRUGID[Count,]), sep='.'), 1)}
      else {
        assign(paste("r", as.character(respDRUGID[Count,]), sep='.'), 1)}
    }
  }
}
DrugPicker(DRUGID.df)
```

Here I have tried to first make a list to contain each new DRUGIDx value (respDRUGID) as well as a counter (Count) for the total number unique DRUGID values and a new dataframe (DRUGID.df) with just the relevant columns.

The function is supposed to move down the observations and if not NA, then if DRUGID_1 is not in list respDRUGID then create a new column variable 'r.DRUGID' and set value to 1. Also increase the unique count by 1. Otherwise the value of DRUGID_1 is already in list respDRUGID then set r.DRUGID = 1

I think I've seen suggestions for get() and apply() functions, but I'm not following how to use them. The resulting dataframe has to be in the same obs x variable format so merging will align with the survey design person weight variable.

Comment: If you  provide sample data, you are more likely to get help. Providing minimal sample  data with `dput` is preferred

Answer (score 1):

Taking a guess at your data and required result format. Using package tidyverse

```
drug_df <- read.csv(text='
patient,DRUGID_1,DRUGID_2,DRUGID_3
A,1,2,3
B,2,,
C,2,1,
D,3,1,2
')

library(tidyverse)
gather(drug_df, value = "DRUGID", ... = -patient, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  arrange(patient, DRUGID) %>%
  group_by(patient) %>%
  summarize(DRUGIDs = paste(DRUGID, collapse=","))

#   patient DRUGIDs
#    <fctr>   <chr>
# 1       A   1,2,3
# 2       B       2
# 3       C     1,2
# 4       D   1,2,3
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another post that does exactly what I want using stringr, destring, sapply and grepl. This works well after combining each variable into a string.

[Creating dummy variables in R based on multiple chr values within each cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40676666/creating-dummy-variables-in-r-based-on-multiple-chr-values-within-each-cell)

Many thanks to epi99 whose post helped think about the problem in another way.